# for loop keeps making my program crash c#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have a application which programs firmware to a circuit board. In the application you can program a single board, or a tray. When programming a tray you can only load 14 at a time.
The user may want to program say 30 boards, so I want the program to program the 14 boards and then tell the user they need to reload a tray.
At the moment I only have one board to practice on, so I have just been reprogramming the same one pretending its a tray.
I have tried to resolve this using loops but when I press the start button it all freezes and stops responding.

The following is my code:

```
    private void setFirmwareMultiple()
    {
        clearTicksandCrosses();
        string firmwareLocation = Firmware(productComboBox.Text); //get the firmware location
        string STPath = @"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\FalconexTest\FalconexTest\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe"; //file location

        string result; //set string
        string result2; //set string 
        int counter = 0;


        int numberOfBoards = int.Parse(numberOfBoardsTextBox.Text);
        while (numberOfBoards > counter) { 

          for (int i = 0; i > 14; i = i + 1) { 
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(); //new process start info
        start.FileName = STPath; //set file name
        start.Arguments = "-C -ME -p " + firmwareLocation + " -v -Run"; //set arguments
        start.UseShellExecute = false; //set shell execute (need this to redirect output)
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect output
        start.RedirectStandardInput = true; //redirect input
        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //hide window
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; //create no window
                string picNumber = i.ToString();

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start)) //create process
        {
            programmingTextBlock.Text = "Board Programming...";
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                  new Action(delegate { }));

            try
            {

                while (process.HasExited == false) //while open
                {
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); //send enter key

                }

                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) //create stream reader
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd(); //read till end of process
                    File.WriteAllText("File.txt", result); //write to file
                }
                saveReport();
            }
            catch { } //so doesn't blow up
            finally
            {
                int code = process.ExitCode; //get exit code
                codee = code.ToString(); //set code to string
                File.WriteAllText("Code.txt", codee); //save code

                if (code == 0)
                {
                    tick1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                            counter = counter + 1;
                }
              else
                        {
                            cross1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        }

                programmingTextBlock.Text = "";

                    }
                }

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Load new boards");

        }
    }
    }
```

I have put the total amount of boards the user wants in the for loop.

I think it maybe to do with the for loop. Because at first, in the for loop, I accidently put (i<14) and it caused it to run fine, however it then didn't stop.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thank you in advance,
Lucy

Comment: The condition in the `for` loop is a _continue_ condition. So the loop is only entered if `i > 14` which never happens as it's initialized with `0`. So your "accident" with `i <14` actually was correct. Can't tell at first glance why it didn't stop then. Please take the time to edit your question and format the code for more readability.

Comment: None of the code in your for loop will ever be executed.  Therefore you have an infinite while loop.

Comment: okay thank you! I'll try it out now

Comment: so what would I set i to? I'm confused

Comment: You have  `while (numberOfBoards > counter) { for (int i = 0; i > 14; i = i + 1) { ` so for each iteration you're running it 14 times, and counter only gets incremented if the return code is zero. What value is numberOfBoards, and use the debugger to step through and see if counter is even being incremented.

Comment: okay thank you, also why have i been downvoted?

Comment: When I went through the debugger, it doesn't even enter the for loop, it gets to the i < 14, and then skips everything

Comment: I would suggest that you do a quick google search and read up on how to do a simple `for loop`

Answer (score 2):

As the code stands now, your `for` loop's content never gets executed. The condition in the `for` loop is a *continue* condition. Since `i` is initialized with `0` the condition `i > 14` is never met. So the result is an infinite outer `while` loop.

Your first "accident" with `i < 14` was correct. But then the loop did not stop, because your inner `while` loop never finishes:

```
while (process.HasExited == false) //while open
{
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); //send enter key
}
```

At first, please don't compare a `bool` to `true` or `false`. A simple `while (!process.HasExited)` is enough.

Secondly, you have to [refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.refresh) your process instance to update the `HasExited` property correctly:

```
while (!process.HasExited) //while open
{
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); //send enter key
    process.Refresh(); // update the process's properties!
}
```

<sup>You may also consider to add a `Thread.Sleep(...)` in that loop.</sup>

Comment: Still keeps freezing :(

Comment: @lucycopp Did you verify that the the process _does_ exit?

Comment: When I went through the debugger, it doesn't even enter the for loop, it gets to the i < 14, and then skips everything

Comment: @lucycopp, this is not possible. The looping with i < 14 WILL enter on each iteration of the outer while looping, because the i is set to 0 and 0 is less than 14...

Comment: i went through the debugger and it didn't

Comment: @lucycopp you took out the whole loop? Keep going, that's what we call debugging. Now start to re-enter parts of the loop's body and debug what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

```
while (numberOfBoards > counter) { 

      for (int i = 0; i > 14; i = i + 1) {
```

In the code above, the for loop will never be executed, because i will be always less than 14.

Because this, counter will never increment, and than, the while will never finish.

But besides this, your approach to the looping is wrong. The following example (fully test program) is something you should do instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int numberOfBoards = 35;

            for (; numberOfBoards > counter; i++, counter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Counter {0}/i {1}", counter, i);

                //call your thread here.
                //make sure that he exists.
                //use somekind of timeout to finish
                //alert the user in case of failure but move to the next anyway to avoid an infinite looping.

                if (i == 13) i = 0;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @lucycopp, because you are incrementing the "counter" inside the "finally" block, but it will be executed only if an exception happens...

Comment: that's not true, the whole sense of a `finally` block is to be executed in _every_ case. The reason for the freeze is the inner while loop. See my answer

Comment: You are write @RenéVogt. Sorry for the misunderstood.